# SSRS subscription with Embedded datasource

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subscription, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I made a SSRS report using the embedded data source and its working fine.
Now I want to create a subscription for my report but getting an error: "*subscription cannot be created because the credentials used to run the report are not stored*" However I stored connection string in the data source.
[image]

[image]

I don't know where I am missing, any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than one data source in the report? Also, if you the report in a Visual Studio project, try to delete the report from the Report Manager and deploy it again from Visual Studio.

Comment: yes, I have more than one data source and each are embedded. I am trying to create a subscription of each report separately.

Comment: the connection string is Expression Based, i don't think that works